# Laravel - Model Eloquent without relationships

Tags: php, laravel-8

i trying to load all rows from a model without the relationship.

The attributes $with it not event set on my Event model but when i do

```
$events = Event::all();
```

all my relationship are loaded, and i can see all the query with the dbquerylog.

i don't understand why theses relationship are loaded,

Please help me !
Thanks you.

I'm using Laravel 8.

here's an example.

```
class Event extends Model {

  public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
  }

  public function items2() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item2::class);
  }

  public function items3() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item3::class);
  }

  public function items4() {
    return $this->hasOne(Item4::class);
  }


}


$events = Event::all();
```

Comment: That code shouldn't load any relationships. Do you have a `foreach($events as $event)` later in your code? Are you testing this via `DB::enableQueryLog(); $events = Event::all(); dd(DB::getQueryLog());`? You should only see the `SELECT * FROM events;` query with that code.

Comment: i did check this and i can sell ALL queries for all relationships, its insance, i dont know why, i keep knocking my head on my desk, 

has you said, there's no way that my relations should be loaded

Comment: @TimLewis, hmm yeahr your right, im doing a foreach after,

but once i get my collection, im doing ->toArray(), and then iterate over the array variables instead of the collection variables

Comment: Your model doesn't have `protected $with = [...];` in it, right? I don't see any other reason your relationships would be loaded; that's not Laravel behaviour by default...

Comment: Another example you can try, `dd(Event::first()->relationLoaded('items'));` and that should be `false`. Or, in a loop: `foreach(Event::all() as $event){ Log::info($event->relationLoaded('items') ? 'Yes' : 'No'); }`; should see a bunch of `No` in `storage/logs/laravel.log` (or `laravel-{date}.log`)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a single instance of a model object, you can do:

```
$obj->withoutRelations();
```

Answer (score 2):

As laravel documentations says you can use `without`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

**Model**

```
protected $with = ['item1','item2','item3','item4'];
```

---

**Controller**

```
$events = Event::without(['item1','item2','item3','item4'])->get();
```

Comment: i did try this, all() doesnt work, i needed to use get() , when i use get, i still get all my relations

Comment: @Thapipo. Ok, maybe you should override `setWith` function in your model too

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem one day, and it turned out that I was using relation in scope method. Because of this relation values were added to response.

Check out this example:

```
class Event extends Model {

  public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
  }

  [...]

  public function scopeItemsGreen() {
    return $this->items->every(function ($item) {
      return $item->color == 'green';
  });
}
```